# How to redirect the checkout complete page without using rules in drupal commerce 2.x

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I need to redirect the checkout complete page with a link on that page . Once user click on that link get redirect to home page without using rules module in drupal 8.

Comment: When you say "the checkout complete page" you mean the last step of this page ? You don't want to show to the end-client the "Thanks page" right ?